# ng2-bootstrap - No provider for TimepickerConfig when imported into a separate module

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using ng2-bootstrap v1.2.5.

In my app I load two Timepicker components into a parent component using `@ViewChild`. I originally did this by declaring the ExampleComponent directly in the AppModule. This approach worked fine.

I now want to move ExampleComponent into its own module (ExampleModule). While the module is new, there are no code changes in the ExampleComponent. However, when Timepicker is imported into ExampleComponent I now get a "No provider for TimepickerConfig!" error.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
/**
 * AppModule
 */
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declaration: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        Ng2BootstrapModule,
        ExampleModule,
        ... etc.
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}


/**
 * ExampleModule
 */
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        Ng2Bootstrap,
        ... etc.
    ],
    exports: [ ExampleComponent ]
})
export class ExampleModule {}


/**
 * ExampleComponent
 */
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {TimepickerComponent} from 'ng2-bootstrap/timepicker';

export class ExampleComponent {
    @ViewChild('startTimepicker') startTimepicker: TimepickerComponent;
    @ViewChild('endTimepicker') endTimepicker: TimepickerComponent;

    ... etc.
}
```

What is causing the new importing error?

Comment: I suggest reproducing in a plunker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In addition to [Raul's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6678976/raul-vargas-mu%C3%B1oz) suggestion of importing TimepickerModule instead of just the component, the TimpickerConfig class needs to be explicitly provided, i.e. imported and added to the provider list.

Pseudo-code:

```
import {TimepickerModule, TimepickerConfig} from 'ng2-bootstrap/timepicker';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TimepickerModule,
        ... etc.
    ],
    exports: [ ExampleComponent ],
    providers: [ TimepickerConfig ]
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

Comment: Or `providers: [ TimepickerConfig, TimepickerActions ]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the way you are importing the ng2-bootstrap into you new module, try to import only the time picker:

```
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/timepicker';
```

and in your imports array will look like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TimepickerModule,
        ... etc.
    ],
    exports: [ ExampleComponent ]
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

> This way is even better than import ng2Bootstrap directly becuse you
>   only import the module that you need and not all the modules.